# Is it possible to convert a TextPointer to an Integer

Tags: c#, .net

I have been editing some long existing code to implement some new functionality. this requires replacing a textbox with a richtextbox whilst keeping the existing implementation the same. the rich text box had comparable properties to the textbox until i got to the caretindex. The original line (which worked for a textbox) was:

```
this.ViewModel.Body = this.ViewModel.Body.Insert(this.txtEditor.CaretIndex, link);
```

so when i changed "txtEditor" to a richtextbox i implemented this:

```
this.ViewModel.Body = this.ViewModel.Body.Insert(this.txtEditor.CaretPosition, link);
```

i believe these are similar however "Caret Position" is of type TextPointer whereas "CaretIndex" was an integer and the Body.Insert method will only take an integer as its first parameter.

Is there any way to convert a TextPointer to and Integer and if so, how is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat convoluted, but it is possible to get the caret index using some hacks:

```
var start = txtEditor.Document.ContentStart;
var here = txtEditor.CaretPosition;
var range = new TextRange(start, here);
int indexInText = range.Text.Length;
```

To use:

```
this.ViewModel.Body = this.ViewModel.Body.Insert(indexInText, link);
```

Comment: i'm assuming you meant to use "here" instead of "caret"?
I like it though. thanks!